# Delete everything in each row after first | occurence in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

My text file is like this:

```
aa/asdhaetcal02acjjaj 2397 hah|asd93hoa|
azxc./asdh5656al02acj4536|asd93hoa|
azxc./asdhceacjjaj 236y3vh|asd93hoa|
```

And I want it to be like:

```
aa./asdhaetcal02acjjaj 2397 hah
hazxc./asdh5656al02acj4536
azxc./asdhceacjjaj 236y3vh
```

This is just an example. I have over 1k lines. I am looking forward to delete everything from each row after first occurrence of "|"

Answer (score 1):

Press ctrl+h and select regular expression

find what: `(?-s)\|.*`

replace with: nothing

Answer (score 0):

Do a search and replace (control -H) using regular expressions, and use:

```
\|.*?\|
```

as your regex, and replace with nothing.  That should get rid of each `|blahblah|` block.

To erase everything from the first | to the next newline, you can use

```
\|*.\n
```

Comment: in the original text file | occurs more than one in few rows. i tried the above, but does not remove everything after the first | from rows.

Comment: Try the second regex... :)